# Find special characters in FileMaker with normal letter

Tags: function, filemaker

I want to search for "Cole" in FileMaker. When I search for that string, I want to find entries like "Čole". When I use the internal search function of FileMaker, this entry does not show in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the language you have selected for indexing the searched field. For example, if the selected language is Czech or Unicode, then you will get the behavior you describe. When the language is English or Default, you will get the behavior you expect.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is it possible to search for different languages? For example Czech and Turkish? Search for "C" finds "Č" and "Ç"?

Comment: I don't know. Claris did not publish specifications for the language settings, and what they did publish is wrong. At least on my system, searching for "c" in a text field indexed as Default finds "Cole", "Čole" and "Çole". In any case, a field can have only one indexing language - though you could have a calculation field that copies the text field but uses a different indexing language and then search both of them using an OR find.

Comment: I'm using FileMaker Pro 18. If I change the language to Czech in the field settings and search for "Cole", it doesn't find "Čole". Why that?

Comment: A record with "Čole" exists.

Comment: Because in the Czech language the Č character is a separate letter of the alphabet and the expectation is that in a sorted list Ča will come after Cz, not between Ca and Cb.

Comment: Doesn't the [Default] language setting do exactly what you want? Or, for that matter, even the [English] language?

Comment: If I change the field language setting to english, it also doesn't find it.

Comment: Ok, you're right. If I change the language setting to english, FileMaker finds it! Great, thanks!